# Appium: How to scroll the screen when there are two scrollers available?

Tags: java, automation, appium

Note that i'm working on android application using java.There are two scrollers on the page, one to scroll the whole screen & another one is to select the skills among the list provided. Have a look of the code shown below that i'm using currently to scroll the screen,

```
    Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
    int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
    System.out.println("s="+scrollStart);
    Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
    int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions2.getHeight(); i++) {
     driver.swipe(0,scrollStart2,0,scrollEnd2,2000);
    }
```

As a result, first it scrolls all the skills from the list(A to z) & then scrolls the whole screen, at the end it gives me the result i want but consumes a lot time in scrolling all the skills which is not required. Instead i just want to scroll whole screen to click on the button shown at most bottom of the page. Please help me to figure out this!

Comment: What happens when you set the scroll pointers (start and end) to some values for the outer scroll? Ideally, if you can mimic it manually, it can be achieved via code as well. Just that you would need to give the co-ordinates correctly.

Comment: I tried with start & end coordinates also & it identifies both which is the reason it scrolls from start to end. So basically it serves my purpose to reach out to the end but what my concern is , it takes much time in scrolling first scroller & which is not required.